# Can't update a returned element.style.left, why?

Tags: javascript, html

I return an elements left position and want to change it later on inside a loop but it doesn't work. I get an invalid left-hand side in assignment error.

Honestly I don't get it. It only fails to update the px if I return the style via a function, so why is this the case? I can't think of any reason since for me this makes perfect sense.

```
function pos(index) {
    return wrapper.children[index].style.left;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  wrapper.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
  pos(i) = Math.random() * w + 'px';;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do here?

Comment: sorry its w for width. Well basically it scatters the divs across the entire width of the screen.

Comment: @tymeJV it can be anything though, such as 100 + "px"...it just wont work.

Comment: This code makes no sense.

Comment: @Rupert but I mean I return wrapper.children[index].style.left and then update the px. At least that is what im trying to achieve

Comment: Why are you passing the index to pos when you can pass the actual div you created?

Comment: @Toni got my reasons. Im writing a really big program (2k lines of code) and I need to reduce the amount of repetition for some areas such as the line im trying to return in this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not returning a pointer to left, you are returning the value.

You either need to send the value to pos or return style.

```
function pos(index, px) {
    wrapper.children[index].style.left = px;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    wrapper.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    pos(i, Math.random() * w + 'px');
}
```

or

```
function pos(index) {
    wrapper.children[index].style;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    wrapper.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    pos(i).left = Math.random() * w + 'px';
}
```

Comment: You are right. Assuming I want to leave out the .left part though, what techniques are there?

Comment: I see, thank you for pointing out this logical mistake. Im capable of writing really crazy things but sometimes I get those blockers : (

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function pos(index) {
    return wrapper.children[index].style;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   wrapper.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
   var style = pos(i);
   style.left = Math.random() * w + 'px';
}
```

Your function returns the object you want, but you cannot modify it (it is no l-value). You have to store it in a variable first (which is an l-value).

Comment: Nope, it fails as well since that wont change anything.

Comment: Actually, you can also skip that part with the variable (as epascarello shows)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you need:

```js
var newElement,
  i,
  wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  //add the element to the wrapper
  wrapper.appendChild(getPositionedElement());

}

function getPositionedElement(){
  //Width, I don't know where you want to get this from
  var w = 1000,
      //create a new element
      el = document.createElement('div');
  //set the left position property
  el.style.left = Math.random() * w + 'px';
  return el;
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  
}

#wrapper div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Nope, im explicitely trying to do this via a function. The original code is really complex so im trying to reduce the amount of repetition.

Comment: Ok, now it's wrapped in a function ;)